# How to convert 3 or more spaces to a hyphen conditionally in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I want to convert multiple spaces to a hyphen.

For example, if there are 3 or more consecutive spaces between words in a string, then I want to convert them to a hyphen.

original string :

```
 $x="Hello    world! I am new        here.
```

string after execution:

```
 Hello-world! I am new-here
```

I have tried the following, but it does not seem to work properly.

```
 <?php
 $str="Hello    world! I am new     here";
 echo preg_replace("/.*\s{3}/","-",$str);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please,try this:-

```
<?php
$str="Hello    world! I am new     here";
 echo preg_replace("/\s{3,}/","-",$str);
?>
```

Output:-http://prntscr.com/7bd9nk

Note: it will take care of any number number of spaces equal to or greater than 3. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use `preg_replace("/ {3,}/", "-", $str)`. The  matches a literal space and `{3,}` indicates matching 3 *or more* of the preceding character.

Your regex will replace any sequence of characters (`.*`) followed by exactly 3 (`{3}`) whitespace characters (`\s`) including tabs, newlines, etc...

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
echo preg_replace("/\s\s\s+/", "-", $str);
```

Comment: It probably doesn't matter in this case, but `\s` matches all kinds of whitespace characters, not just spaces.